# What's a method for evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{\log(n)}}{2^n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How can one evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{\log(n)}}{2^n}$$

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Write the ratio as

$$e^{\log^2(n)-n\log(2)}$$